# How to get the summary from lm() in a table?

Tags: r, lm

I have trained lm model on a dataset and generated the summary of the model using summary() function. How to get the summary in a table?

Comment: `data <- broom::tidy(model)`

Comment: You can also check out the `xtable` and `stargazer` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `broom::tidy` :

```
model <- lm(mpg~cyl, mtcars)
broom::tidy(model)

#  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 (Intercept)    37.9      2.07      18.3  8.37e-18
#2 cyl            -2.88     0.322     -8.92 6.11e-10
```